# How do I remove white space from error message on Bootstrap 4 form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, forms, whitespace, spacing

I am using Bootstrap 4 on my form. Bootstrap is adding white space which is throwing off my design. I'd like to get rid of the spacing. It appears below the textarea and when the form is submitted incorrectly it appears below the input fields. I have googled and checked inspect but I still can't figure out what exactly is causing the space.

I did figure out that when I remove the form group class the white space disappears but so does the error message, I do not wish to get rid of the error message. I noticed on inspect that user agent shows and it seems to be adding 1 rem to the margin bottom but again none of the things I've tried have overridden it. I tried adding mb-0 and m-0 on the div class and input class. I tried adding margin 0 and padding 0 on help-block.with-errors, form-control, form-group and list-unstyled within the css sheet.

Here are pictures of the form before and after the form is submitted:

[image]

[image]

```css
.form{
  width:97.6%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
input, textarea{
  font-size:14.5px;
  padding:8px;
  border-radius:6px;
  border:1px solid #676464;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
}
input{
  height:36px; 
}    
textarea{
  height:200px;
}    
input[type=submit]{
  border-radius:6px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:#2e2e2e;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  color:#4f9190;
  font-size:22px;
  font-weight:normal;
}
.help-block.with-errors, .form-control, .form-group, ul.list-unstyled{
  color: #ff5050;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<form class="form" id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

                    <div class="messages"></div>

                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                     <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    <input id="form_name" type="text" class="" name="name" placeholder="*Name:" required="required" data-error="Name is required.">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                     <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                     <input id="form_email" type="email" class="" name="email" placeholder="*Email:" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    <textarea id="form_message" class="" name="message" placeholder="Questions, Message, Quote..."  required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="submit" class="" value="Send Message">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>

                </form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>        
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js" integrity="sha256-dHf/YjH1A4tewEsKUSmNnV05DDbfGN3g7NMq86xgGh8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="contact.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the [line-height property](https://cssreference.io/property/line-height/), see my code sample below where i added `line-height: 15px;`

```
.help-block.with-errors, .form-control, .form-group, ul.list-unstyled {
 color: #ff5050;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 line-height: 15px;
}
```

Here is the output: `https://i.postimg.cc/VvpggtWJ/test.jpg`